# react-bootstrap-table double header

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Using `react-bootstrap-table`, I have created a table as follows:

```
<BootstrapTable data={props.instances} hover condensed selectRow={props.selectRowOpts}>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'interval_value'} dataSort>{'Interval'}</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'status_name'} dataSort>{'Status'}</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'started_ts'} dataSort>{'Started'}</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'completed_ts'} dataSort>{'Completed'}</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'last_runtime'} dataSort>{'RT'}</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'attempts'} dataSort>{'Attempts'}</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'pid'} dataSort>{'PID'}</TableHeaderColumn>
  <TableHeaderColumn dataField={'node_instance_id'} dataSort isKey>{'ID'}</TableHeaderColumn>
</BootstrapTable>
```

However, this is giving me some funny results. This is what the table looks like for me (table is located within a `Tab` from `react-bootstrap`:

[image]

What did I do wrong? The strangest part is that the header on top works, but the header actually attached to the table does nothing.

**Edit: table after reimporting css**
In my `index.html` I now have:

However, while that fixes the double header issue, it keeps the issue of misaligned header columns. The table now looks like so:

[image]

I also tried the `react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css` file but got the same results.

**Update:**
Using one of the headers to perform a sort fixes the alignment issue. But why would it be broken to begin with?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From their [GitHub Issues](https://github.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/issues/151)

> You need re-import the css file :)

You can see this working in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/tyrsius/pen/wMwjZr?editors=001). The issue shows up if you remove the boostrap-table css file from the settings menu.

```
https://rawgit.com/AllenFang/react-bootstrap-table/master/css/react-bootstrap-table.min.css
```

Comment: New questions regarding the misalignment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34054567/react-bootstrap-table-misaligned-header-columns